# I am getting blank email from php and js

Tags: php, html, ajax, email

Please help me with decoding what the real issue is. The issue is that I keep getting a blank email, despite all my tweaking and research on this code. Below are my html, javascript (ajax) and php code.

HTML code: file named contact.html

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name *</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email *</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subject *</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message *</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
        </div>                        
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

AJAX code:file named main.js

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),

        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

PHP code: file named sendemail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'email@email.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
?>
```

with this I keep on getting a blank email as depicted below

```
Name:

Email: Blank

Phone: Blank

Subject: Blank

Message: Blank
```

Comment: Please format your HTML because it's difficult to read like you posted it.

Comment: Erabor, MatVP's answer suggests to remove the "@" symbols in order to display errors, I agree with that, give it a try (remove them all).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with-out the die() at the end of your script? I think you might be killing your page too fast.

Also try creating a catch like this :

```
if (!mail(...)) 
{
   // Reschedule for later try or panic appropriately!
}
```

Furthermore, you are suppressing warnings with @ before mail();
Try removing the @.

Edit : Also, try removing the trims.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set data while calling ajax, may be this is your problem.

Comment: I tested the code, the data is properly sent by ajax and properly received by PHP. I can't find the cause for the email to be blank.

Answer (score 0):

When I test your code then I see that there fires a GET-request although you define the mehtod as POST in the form attribute. (Maybe that´s why jQuery use GET as default...). So the $_POST['name'] is empty because the parameter is in $_GET['name'].

And I can´t see the request parameters when I´m submiting the form. (Maybe that´s why the 'data' property is not set..)

Please try to complete the $.ajax with these:

```
method: 'POST'
data: $(this).serialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

A BIG THANKS to ALL of you guys(@Mateusz Klimentowicz,@Mat VP,@Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez ,@ Vladimir Nu). I actually followed your instructions and ended up correcting both the JS file and the PHP file as shown below:

JS file:

```
// Contact form

var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

While the PHP code became this below:

```
<?php

    $status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contacting us. As soon as possible  we will contact you!'
);

    $fail = array(
    'type'=>'fail',
    'message'=>'Please try again. Your mail could not be delivered!'
);  

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 


$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'email@mail.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

header('Content-type: application/json');

if($success){
    echo json_encode($status);
}
else{
    echo json_encode($fail);
}
?>
```

And after using this code as stated below, i end up not getting any blank page email. Email is now delievered with it's content. Thanks a bunch.