# unsuccessful clearing of form values/content after successful submission

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Each time, I submit my form, the expected reset function is not clearing my form. Please how should I clear my form my codes(HTML, PHP, JS) follows below.

HTML codes:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email *</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>                        
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Subject *</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Message *</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code is below:

```
jQuery(function($) {'use strict',
 ...... 
 ......

var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
// Serialize the form data.
var formData = $(form).serialize();
var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    beforeSend: function(){
        form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
    }
}).done(function(data){
    $("#main-contact-form")[0].reset();
    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
  });
 ......
 ......
 });
```

And last of all is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$status = array(
'type'=>'success',
'message'=>'Thank you for contacting us. As soon as possible  we will      contact you!'
);

$fail = array(
'type'=>'fail',
'message'=>'Please try again. Your mail could not be delivered!'
);  

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 


$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'email@mail.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

header('Content-type: application/json');

if($success){
    echo json_encode($status);
}
else{
    echo json_encode($fail);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you stop using `@`, instead of ignoring errors or possible errors, handle them.

Comment: Didn't you post this already/similar? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38769155/

Comment: I believe form_status var is not defined inside "done" function... just in case try to redefine it there... Also check browser debug console for errors.

Comment: Your *Stealth* edit adding what an answer below contains `$("#main-contact-form")[0].reset();` is shameful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am getting blank email from php and js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38769155/)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it was indeed a Stealth Edit, for which I am sorry for when pasting I made a mistake of adding my former JS code and not the present version. The former code was without $("#main-contact-form")[0].reset(); it was when Rax Shah suggested it that I remembered that I did not add present code version...

Comment: @SergioBernardo the variable form_status was defined already inside the "done" function, `.done(function(data){
    $("#main-contact-form")[0].reset();
    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("#main-contact-form")[0].reset();
```

Comment: Ooops! Sorry for in my code, I did not edit it. But I just did. What i mean is that I had used this earlier before pasting my code in here, but i kind of forgot to add the fresh version                                                                              $("#main-contact-form")[0].reset();

Comment: try this one $('#formId').trigger("reset");

Comment: Just tried that      ($('#formId').trigger("reset");   and it still did not clear the content or values in my form.

Comment: Thanks Sir @ Rax Shah, I used the two functions you gave me earlier i discovered that instead of me using "main-contact-form" i used the wrong ID and they both are working `$('#main-contact-form')[0].reset();` and `$('#main-contact-form').trigger("reset")` I am very grateful to you guys.  Epodax,  Sergio Bernardo and  Fred -ii. Thanks a bunch

Comment: And  One important thing i was actually missing was that I actually used the reset function before I outputted the obtained message from the server. If you look at my code above, that was why I think it was not resetting the form when the function reset was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing i was actually missing was that I actually used the reset function before I outputted the obtained message from the server.Looking at my code above, one will discover that i have in my javascipt code the line below:

```
.done(function(data){
$("#main-contact-form")[0].reset();
form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
});
```

which I corrected to become this one below:

```
.done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        $('#main-contact-form')[0].reset();
        //$('#main-contact-form').trigger("reset");
    });
```

A BIG THANKS TO YOU GUYS!